# switch in fragment no event

Tags: java, android

I'm using the MainActivity as a FragmentActivity and a TabsPagerAdapter as FragmentPagerAdapter.
I have Statusbar as a fragment (and a page of the tabs) and adding a switch to the fragment with this code, nothing happes during event.

```
public class Statusbar extends Fragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mLinearLayout = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.statusbar_fragment,
                container, false);
        Switch s = (Switch) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swt1);
        if (s != null) {
            s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
        return mLinearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

what can be the problem? If I remove this:
`if (s != null) { ... }` it crashes with a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this:

```
View mLinearLayout = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.statusbar_fragment,
            container, false);
    Switch s = (Switch) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swt1);
```

change it to:

```
View mLinearLayout = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.statusbar_fragment,
            container, false);
    Switch s = (Switch) mLinearLayout .findViewById(R.id.swt1);
```

Comment: can I also know what's the difference between them?

Comment: In a fragment, the view gets inflated, and that is why we use the view to find the element.. while in an activity you dont use any view. Glad it helped

Comment: yep. I had to wait 12 mins ;)